# Как посмотреть цепочку Tor в обычном браузере или сторонней прграмме?

Tags: сеть, xubuntu, трафик

Настроил перенаправление трафика через Тор по [этой](https://cryptopunks.org/article/forward+all+the+traffic+to+tor/) инструкции. С помощью какой программы я смогу отследить маршрут трафика? Например в Tor Browser это реализованно так как на [скрине](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHc7.png) (там показывает через какие IP проходят пакеты прежде чем попасть на сайт). Мне нужно так же, только, либо в обычном браузере либо в отдельной программе

Comment: если кратко, то задаёшь контрольный сокет/порт и подключаешься к нему каким-либо клиентом, поддерживающим [tor-протокол](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt). AFAIK какого-либо общепринятого CLI-клиента на сегодняшний день нет, так что предлагаю набросать свой на питоне. Дабы не реализовывать протокол самому целиком, есть готовая [библиотечка](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html). Вероятнее всего тебя будут интересовать `get_circuits()`/`get_circuit()`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer было бы неплохо уметь набросать свой на питоне. Я понимаю что происходит в коде который вы скинули, но как набросать свой не представляю, так как не знаю возможностей Python. А можно ведь добавить несколько портов?

Comment: @Fat-Zer что должно быть в коде в строке `controller=Controller.from_port()` ибо если оставить так или добавить аргумент 80 к примеру, то синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: как-то так: `controller=Controller.from_port(port=9051)`, где `9051` — это `ControlPort`, указанный в [конфиге tor'а](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort)... да, если предпочитаешь, есть ещё [java'вская версия](https://github.com/guardianproject/jtorctl).

Comment: а ещё можешь глянуть в сторону [nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/)...

Comment: @Fat-Zel Nyx это ровно то, что нужно. Напишите ответ,  чтобы отметить ваш ответ как решение.

Comment: пока, откровенно говоря, лень писать... может через пару дней напишу, если не забуду... и я вполне не против, если сам напишешь...

Answer (score -1):

Как и посоветовал [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer) нужно использовать программу [Nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/). Чтобы установить в Debian подобных дистрах `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nyx* -y`.
Для запуска зайти в терминал и прописать команду `nyx` , естественно при настроенном перенаправлении трафика через Tor.
Остальное в комментариях к вопросу.